# Python function "remembering" earlier argument (**kwargs)

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have some objects that have a dictionary of attributes, `obj.attrs`. The constructor for these objects accepts a dict and/or `**kwargs`, for convenience.

It looks a little like this:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, attrs={}, **kwargs):
        for arg in kwargs:
            attrs[arg] = kwargs[arg]
        self.attrs = attrs
```

Such that `Thing({'color':'red'})` does the same as `Thing(color='red')`.

My problem is that the constructor somehow *remembers* the last `attrs` value passed to it.

For example:

```
>>> thing1 = Thing(color='red')
>>> thing2 = Thing()
>>> thing2.attrs
{'color': 'red'}
```

...but `thing2.attrs` should just be an empty dict! `{}`

This made me wonder if this isn't a problem with using *both* `**kwargs` *and* an argument like `attrs={}`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same principle as in ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with using default arguments is that only one instance of them actually exists.  When you say `attrs={}` in your **init** method definition, that single default {} instance is the default for every call to that method (it doesn't make a new default empty dict every time, it uses the same one).

The problem is that if there's only one `attrs` in existence and then for every instance of Thing you say `self.attrs = attrs`, the `self.attrs` member variable for every single one of your instance is pointing to the single shared default instance of `attrs`.

The other question is, isn't this completely redundant?  You can use `**kwargs` to pass in keyword/value args or a dictionary.  If you just defined this:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for arg in kwargs:
            self.attrs[arg] = kwargs[arg]
```

All of these strategies still work:

```
thing1 = Thing(color='red')

thing2 = Thing(**{'color':'red'})

my_dict = {'color' : 'red'}
thing3 = Thing(**my_dict)
```

So if you simply define and use Thing that way, you'll avoid your problem altogether.

Comment: So I take it the problem isn't **kwargs, it's the default argument?

Comment: Correct.  You have to be really careful when using default arguments because the default argument's value gets created once when Python processes the `def` statement and then the reference to the same default is used over & over again.

Comment: I think the other major point is that everything you want to do can be done with `kwargs`.  You probably don't need `attrs` at all.

Comment: Accepted as it explains the problem and demonstrates a solution.

Comment: Good to know! Can't believe I've been programming Python for 3 years now and just ran into this problem.

Answer (score 2):

`attrs` is a *reference* to a dictionary. When you create a new object, `self.attrs` points to that dictionary. When you assign a value from a `kwargs`, it goes to this dictionary.

Now, when you create a second instance, it's `self.attrs` also points to that same dictionary. Thus, it gets whatever data is in that dictionary.

For a nice discussion of this see ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) here on stackoverflow. Also see [Default Parameter Values](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) in Python on [effbot](http://effbot.org).

Answer (score 2):

What about changing the signature so that the dictionary is created each time

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        self.attrs = attrs or {}
        self.attrs.update(kwargs)
```

Comment: Instead of the `for` loop you could just say `attrs.update(kwargs)`

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your code to:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        attrs = {} if attrs is None else attrs
        for arg in kwargs:
            attrs[arg] = kwargs[arg]
        self.attrs = attrs
```

As others have pointed out, the value of a default argument is evaluated once, at definition time, not each time the function is called.  By using a mutable container, each addition to the container is seen by all subsequent calls because each call uses the same container as the default value.

It might be that you only ever use attrs as a way to provide initial values, and you never meant to share dicts at all.  In that case, use this:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        self.attrs = {}
        if attrs:
            self.attrs.update(attrs)
        for arg in kwargs:
            self.attrs[arg] = kwargs[arg]
```

Comment: That's really sad. Now I have a hundred init routines to change... Thanks though!

Comment: @blob8108: I had another thought about what you're really trying to do, and have edited it in above.

Answer (score 1):

Just for what it's worth - we can avoid the "`attrs` is a shared mutable object" problem by simply not mutating it. Instead of dumping the `kwargs` into `attrs`, dump them both into a new dict. Then the default-argument-object will always be `{}`.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, attrs = {}, **kwargs):
        self.attrs = {}
        # Don't write the loop yourself!
        self.attrs.update(attrs)
        self.attrs.update(kwargs)
```

I'm only mentioning this because everyone's rushing to describe the "use None as a default argument and check for it" idiom, which I personally find rather hackish. sgusc has the right idea: the entire endeavour is not useful, given the general awesomeness of Python's `**kwargs`. :)